# bash alias doesn't carry over with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, gentoo, .bash-profile

I'm curious if there's a way to get my .bash_profile to work when I sudo a program.

For example, I have it set to `alias emerge='emerge -av'` so that I can install software, and it will always ask me if I want to proceed before downloading and installing. However I just noticed when I `sudo emerge foo`, it defaults to just the plain command `emerge foo` instead of `emerge -av foo`.

Only thing that comes to mind to fix this is to also put the alias in root's .bash_profile, but I don't want to have to resort to that since I will always have to make changes in two places when I want to add stuff to my own profile.

Is there another way around this that I'm unfamiliar with?

Comment: I tried putting aliases in root's profile, and they don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash,

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

will cause bash to expand any aliases that come after `sudo`.

Comment: Please can you explain why this works?

Comment: It's simply part of how bash expands aliases.  From the bash manpage: "If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next command word following the alias is also checked for alias  expansion."

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work in combination with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19739018/520061 or how to make it work?

Comment: @SebastianBlask: Because you basically end up running `sudo function _foo() { ...; }; _foo` – that is, trying to invoke bash built-in syntax via `sudo`. Regarding how to make it work, all I can say about that answer by osirisgothra is: 1) http://www.themonolith.com/wp-content/uploads/why-would-you-do-that.jpg 2) no, seriously, _what is the damn point_ in defining a function _inside_ an alias, rather than just _using a function_? 3) unfortunately, you can't call functions with `sudo`, so I recommend putting their content in a shell script.

Comment: @grawity so just like `sudo cd` doesn't work? The point is being able to use sudo with the same commands I can use as a normal user. I figured I could make it a shell script, but then I have to type the whole path with sudo, which I don't have to do with my normal user, but well, if it's just not possible...

Comment: @SebastianBlask: Yes, and it could not _possibly_ work, due to `cd` and the corresponding `chdir()` syscall only affecting the _current_ process, while `sudo` is a standalone program which runs as a separate process and runs the given command in a yet another process. If `cd` was a separate program, it could change its own "working directory", but wouldn't have any way to do the same to its parent (sudo) or grandparent (the interactive shell).

Comment: @SebastianBlask: (I omitted the possibility of making such a `cd` program use the *ptrace* debugging facility to inject code into its parent, and trick the parent into calling `chdir()` itself. This would be a completely useless roundtrip in the direct case, and wouldn't work in the `sudo` case due to the parent still lacking the privileges that `sudo` has obtained.)

Comment: @SebastianBlask: Going in the other direction, if one were to convert `sudo` into a shell built-in command rather than a standalone program, then it couldn't obtain higher privileges than the shell itself. (Currently `sudo` obtains root privileges by having the "setuid" bit set.) And if one granted root privileges to the shell itself, then 1) it would make `sudo cd` pointless as the shell could just use those privileges for direct `cd`, and 2) it would introduce potential security holes (e.g. obtaining root privileges by abusing a bug in the shell's parser).

Comment: @SebastianBlask: If this is on your own system, you can ask `sudo` to preserve the `$HOME` and `$PATH` variables (it's an option in /etc/sudoers, or the `-E` flag as bahamat mentioned); that way, you could run a privileged shell using `sudo -s` and still be able to use your custom aliases, functions, and scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The other way to do it (although in *this* particular instance I recommend Grawity's answer) would be to use the `-E` flag to sudo to inherit the environment.

```
   -E          The -E (preserve environment) option will override the
               env_reset option in sudoers(5)).  It is only available when
               either the matching command has the SETENV tag or the
               setenv option is set in sudoers(5).
```